# Hide field when date ='01/01/1900'

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to hide a field in my report. The following code gives me an error claiming "The formula result must be a Boolean"

```
if 
totext((Date(Year({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}),
            Month({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}),   
              Day({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}))), 'dd/MM/yyyy') ="01/01/1900" 
then
    "" 
else 
    totext((Date(Year({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}),
                Month({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}),
                  Day({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}))),'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: I would use the Surpress field in the Section Expert instead. In Crystal Reports you can tell a field to hide itself automatically when a condition is met, *without* having to check for it in the field itself.

Answer (score 1):

To hide specific fields, right-click on the field and select "Format ..." where  is field, formula etc. Go to the Common tab and click on the button next to "Suppress". Enter a formula that evaluates to True or False. When true, the field will be suppressed:

```
Cheque_Date = Date(1900, 01, 01)
```

You must return a boolean to avoid the issue. For more, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330466/the-result-of-selection-formula-must-be-a-boolean-in-crystal-report)

Comment: I am also using the code if {vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date} in Date(1999,01,01) to Date(1999,06,30) then False else True

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if your solution is put into place, the Formula itself can be simplified to be just `totext((Date(Year({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}), Month({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}), Day({vPolicyPaymentData.Cheque_Date}))),'dd/MM/yyyy')`